# PySpark: Compute row wise aggregations with None values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How do you compute row wise aggregations when there are 'None' values?

For instance, the following code gives me 'None' results when I try to sum:

```
columns = ['US', 'UK', 'Can']
countries.withColumn('sum', sum(countries[col] for col in columns))

+--+--+-----+---+
|id|US| UK  |Can|
+--+--+-----+---+
| 1|50|None |  0|
| 1| 0|100  |  0|
| 1| 0|  0  |125|
| 2|75|  0  |  0|
+--+--+-----+---+
```

Comment: why not try to replace None values with 0 using fillna, then try to compute?

Comment: I could, but it's not the cleanest answer. For instance, what if I want to average the row?

Comment: average should work fine with None, sum won't

Comment: is there a way to temporarily replace none values with 0 so that I don't have to alter a very large dataframe?

Comment: You can do a `deepcopy` of you data frame and then perform operations on it.

Comment: There has to be a more elegant solution? I have many dataframes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a workable answer I found, but would be interested in anything even more elegant. Thanks.

```
columns = ['US', 'UK', 'Can']
countries.withColumn('sum', sum([func.coalesce(col(x), func.lit(0)) for x in columns]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a copy of your data frame using the `copy.deepcopy` in `pyspark` and then replace your nulls with zero and perform sum and average.

```
import copy

countries = spark.createDataFrame([[1,50,None,0], [1,0,100,0],[1,0,0,125],[2,75,0,0]], ['id', 'US','UK','Can'])
_schema = copy.deepcopy(countries.schema)
_countries = countries.rdd.zipWithIndex().toDF(_schema)

_countries=_countries.na.fill(0)

columns = ['US', 'UK', 'Can']
_countries.withColumn('sum', sum(_countries[col] for col in columns))
```

This should give desired without having to change your original data frame.

Comment: I didn't down vote, this but this seems to be a lot of work to merely sum over rows. I would be surprised if there wasn't a more elegant solution. I have about 20 very large dataframes and would hate to have to do this for each one.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to convert to pandas DataFrame, compute the sum, then back to Spark DataFrame (but I don't recommend it). Note the following works because `pandas.Dataframe.sum` defaults to `skipna=True`

```
# Generate data
data = [(1, 50, None, 0), (1, 0, 100, 0), (1, 0, 0, 125), (2, 75, 0, 0)]
countries = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["id", "US", "UK", "Can"])
columns = ['US', 'UK', 'Can']
# Solution
pd_countries = countries.toPandas()
pd_countries['sum'] = pd_countries[columns].sum(axis=1) # default is ignore nan
result = spark.createDataFrame(pd_countries)
result.show()
+---+---+-----+---+-----+                                                       
| id| US|   UK|Can|  sum|
+---+---+-----+---+-----+
|  1| 50|  NaN|  0| 50.0|
|  1|  0|100.0|  0|100.0|
|  1|  0|  0.0|125|125.0|
|  2| 75|  0.0|  0| 75.0|
+---+---+-----+---+-----+
```

Also, note that your original code is performing the following operation

```
sum(countries[c] for c in columns)
# Column<b'(((US + 0) + UK) + Can)'>
# equivalent to (col(US) + 0 + col(UK) + col(Can))
```

In my opinion, the easiest way is to use `na.fill(0)` as suggested by commenter and answer and then compute sum.